# Simulating spatial PDEs in Modelica - Accessing variable values at specific times

Tags: modelica, dymola

This question is somewhat related to a previous question of mine, where I didn't quite get the right solution. Link: [Earlier SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233203/evaluating-variables-at-a-specific-time-in-modelica)

I am solving PDEs which are time variant with one spatial dimension (e.g. the heat equation - see link below). I'm using the numerical method of lines, i.e. discretizing the spatial derivatives yielding a system of ODEs which are readily solved in Modelica (using the Dymola tool). My problems arise when I simulate the system, or when I plot the results, to be precise. The equations themselves appear to be solved correctly, but I want to express the spatial changes in all the discretized state variables at specific points in time rather than the individual time-varying behavior of each discrete state.

The strategy leading up to my problems is illustrated in this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtKLaG0tCgY&noredirect=1), which by the way is not made by me. As you can see at the very end of the tutorial, the time-varying behavior of the temperature is plotted for all the discrete points in the rod, individually. What I would like is a plot showing the temperature through the rod at a specific time, that is the temperature as a function of the spatial coordinate. My strategy to achieve this, which I'm struggling with, is: Given a state vector of N entries:

```
Real[N] T "Temperature";
```

..I would use the `plotArray` Dymola function as shown below.

```
plotArray( {i for i in 1:N}, {T[i] for i in 1:N} )
```

Intuitively, this would yield a plot showing the temperature as a function of the spatial coordiate, or the number in the line of discrete units, to be precise. Although this command yields a result, all T-values appear to be 0 in the plot, which is definitely not the case. My question is: How can I successfully obtain and plot the temperatures at all the discrete points at a given time? Thanks in advance for your help.

The code for the problem is as indicated below.

```
model conduction

   parameter Real rho = 1;
   parameter Real Cp = 1;
   parameter Real L = 1;
   parameter Real k = 1;
   parameter Real Tlo = 0;
   parameter Real Thi = 100;
   parameter Real Tinit = 30;
   parameter Integer N = 10 "Number of discrete segments";
   Real T[N-1] "Temperatures";
   Real deltaX = L/N;

initial equation 
   for i in 1:N-1 loop
     T[i] = Tinit;
   end for;

equation 

   rho*Cp*der(T[1]) = k*( T[2] - 2*T[1] + Thi) /deltaX^2;
   rho*Cp*der(T[N-1]) = k*( Tlo - 2*T[N-1] + T[N-2]) /deltaX^2;

   for i in 2:N-2 loop
     rho*Cp*der(T[i]) = k*( T[i+1] - 2*T[i] + T[i-1]) /deltaX^2;
   end for
   annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2")));

end conduction;
```

**Additional edit:** The simulations show clearly that for example T[3], that is the temperature of discrete segment no. 3, starts out from 30 and ends up at 70 degrees. When I write T[3] in my command window, however, I get T3 = 0.0 in return. Why is that? This is at the heart of the problem, because the `plotArray` function would be working if I managed to extract the actual variable values at specific times and not just 0.0.

**Suggested solution**: This is a rather tedious solution to achieve what I want, and I hope someone knows a better solution. When I run the simulation in Dymola, the software generates a .mat-file containing the values of the variables throughout the time of the simulation. I am able to load this file into MATLAB and manually extract the variables of my choice for plotting. For the problem above, I wrote the following command:

```
plot( [1:9]' , data_2(2:2:18 , 10)' )
```

This command will plot the temperatures (as the temperatures are stored together with their derivates in the data_2 array in the .mat-file) against the respetive number of the discrete segment/element. I was really hoping to do this inside Dymola, that is avoid using MATLAB for this. For this specific problem, the amount of variables was low on account of the simplicity of this problem, but I can easily image a .mat-file which is signifanctly harder to navigate through manually like I just did.

Comment: Your approach looks right in principle.  But since you don't include the source code for your model, it is hard to determine what might be wrong.  If possible, please include the code so that people can try and duplicate your problem and help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: The code has now been added. I hope this is helpful to illustrate the problem. This is a fairly simple problem, but I'm planning to use the solution (i.e. plotting variables for spatial changes) for other more complex problems aswell.

Comment: There are a bunch of Matlab files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dymola 2014 FD01\Mfiles` or whatever your Dymola path is. For some reason, these are not very well documented. Using `dymolaM` you can pass commands from Matlab to Dymola, other helpful commands are `loaddsin`, `setParameterByName` and `dymosim`.

Comment: @matth I've explored some of these functions, and they are quite helpful. I tried, for instance, the function named ``tload``, which more or less enabled me to perform the same actions in Matlab that @Florian Brucker indicated for Dymola in the answer below.

Comment: We do all our post-processing outside of Dymola, for example in MATLAB or Python. Same goes for control of batch simulations and similar stuff. Dymola is fine for the actual modeling, for anything else it's currently not really usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you do not mention it explicitly I assume that you enter your `plotArray` command in Dymola's command window. That won't work directly, since the variables you see there do not include your simulation results: If I simulate your model, and then enter `T[:]` in Dymola's command window, then the printed result is

```
T[:]
 = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
```

I'm not a Dymola expert, and the only solution I've found (to actively store and load the desired simulation results) is quite cumbersome:

```
simulateModel("conduction", resultFile="conduction.mat")
n = readTrajectorySize("conduction.mat")
X = readTrajectory("conduction.mat", {"Time"}, n)
Y = readTrajectory("conduction.mat", {"T[1]", "T[2]", "T[3]"}, n)
plotArrays(X[1, :], transpose(Y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. As far as I can tell from your command calls and figure, it seems as you have plotted three individual temperatures against time, which is not quite what I initially desired, but your methods are (more or less) exactly what I wanted.

Comment: A follow-up to this solution is the following:
Let's say I have 1000 discrete points instead of 10. How do I formulate my Y-matrix in a compact manner to extract all of them? It's fairly tedious to write like
``Y = readTrajectory("conduction.mat",{"T[1]","T[3]",...,"T[999]",n)``.
Recall that I want to plot the temperatures as a function of the spatial coordinate at a specific time.

Comment: @fredrikg: I don't know any short way, but as I said I'm no Dymola expert.