# how to access a variable value at a specific time?

Tags: algorithm, math, modelica

I have tried this code:

```
model var
  Real x;
  Real y;
  Real z;
equation 

  x=6*time;
  when time>=6 then
    z=x;
  end when;
  y=3*z;
end var;
```

But it will give me `y = 3*x`(at time = 6) but from time = 6 while i need it from the beginning.
Any direct method for this problem?

Comment: If I understood correct you want to access a value from the future, which is not possible.

Comment: What's wrong with explicit `y= 3*x`?

Comment: i was trying to make y=3*z from the beginning and not at time=6, but it's not possible to access a future value like marco said.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233203/evaluating-variables-at-a-specific-time-in-modelica

Comment: So would the question rather be: "How to access a future value of a variable in Modelica?" then?

Answer (score 0):

Based on folks comments you now know that Modelica is quite strict in its treatment of time behavior. You could argue that it is a more physical representation of time (quantum and other crazy physics aside), as in you can not time-travel in your code.

Depending on your application there may be ways around your issue. One possibility is to move the time behavior to the initialization. That way you capture the behavior prior to `time=0` and start at `time=0` with the expected behavior.

**For example:**

```
model var

  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time t_zero = 6;
  parameter Real x(fixed=false);

  Real y;
  Real z;

initial equation
  x = 6*t_zero; // or some more complicated set of equations/functions

equation 
  z = x;
  y=3*z;

end var;
```

Recognized this restricts things, potentially too much, but you can have many parameters and have a more complex representation in the initial equation block. You can also call a function `x=func()` where you have performed integrations, etc. to get the value of x at `time=0`.

Hope that helps, either now or in the future.